How to compute molar Gibbs free energy (chemical potential) for single molecule using gaussian09?
I want to calculate the Gibbs free energy of single gas molecule (AsH3) using Gaussian 09, but I am confused between "Thermal correction to Gibbs Free Energy" and "Sum of electronic and thermal Free Energies." which one to use??

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yovT_h7N7x8
